# Putting Generated Classes into the Same Package for Different Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have a couple of JAX-WS webservices and they use the same classes but after generating from wsdl (on client side) the same classes have different packages. I found how to put them into same package using `@xmltype` annotation. But I can't use it as source code is not available. Is it possible somehow fix it while service deployment?

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate the client code from WSDL? If you use maven you can specify the package of generated classes in plugin settings (e.g. apache cxf plugin supports "packagenames" element inside the "wsdlOption" element).

Comment: No, and script is used. All the classes for one WS are getting moved to one package so it does not really matter the actual name of this package I need to split all classes into different packages (only particular classes).

Comment: What for do you need to split generated classes into different packages? I think you want your classes to be visible to your clients classes.

Comment: Ok, for example I have 2 WS's WS1 and WS2. On server side I have data class pckg.Data and it is common for both WS's. Each WS has its own namespace. And after classes were generated from wsdl I have 2 different packages for each WS and I have package1.Data and package2.Data. So I need somehow to put this generated classes into the same package but keep the rest of classes in there own package1 and package2 packages.

Comment: ok, it's clear now. If you are able to modify wsdls, you can extract xsd schema of Data element to it's own scheme with its own namespace and include it to your both wsdls